# Writing game-file-storage with GZip support?

Tags: java

```
    public static void loadModels() {
    try {
        DataInputStream indexFile = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("./cache/models.idx"));
        DataInputStream dataFile = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("./cache/models.dat"));
        int length = indexFile.readInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            int id = indexFile.readInt();
            int invlength = indexFile.readInt();
            byte[] data = new byte[invlength];
            dataFile.readFully(data);
            //System.out.println("ID: "+ id +" Length: "+ invlength +" Data: "+ data);
            Class30_Sub2_Sub4_Sub6.method460(data, id);
        }
        indexFile.close();
        dataFile.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That's my void for loading my models(theres 57056 of them by the way) Method460(data, id); refers to calling the models from the storage.

```
package com.rs.modelcompressor.file;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.rs.modelcompressor.Main;

public class FileController {

private List<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<Model>();

public FileController() {   
}

private byte[] build() {
    byte[] returnValue;
    int i = 0;
    for(Model m : modelList) {
        i += m.getData().length;
    }
    returnValue = new byte[i];
    int offset = 0;
    for(Model model : modelList) {
        Main.getUserInterface().getTextArea().append("Copying Model Data: "+ model.getId()+"\n");
        System.arraycopy(model.getData(), 0, returnValue , offset, model.getData().length);
        offset += model.getData().length;
    }
    return returnValue;
}

public void compress() {
    int offset = 0;
    if(modelList.size() == 0) {
        Main.getUserInterface().getTextArea().append("No models loaded\n");
        return;
    }

    try {
        byte[] data = build();
        Main.getUserInterface().getTextArea().append("Creating data file\n");
        DataOutputStream dataFile = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("models.dat"));
        dataFile.write(data, 0, data.length);
        Main.getUserInterface().getTextArea().append("Length of written data: "+ data.length +"\n");
        dataFile.flush();
        dataFile.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Main.getUserInterface().getTextArea().append("An error occured while writing data file\n");
    }
    try {
        Main.getUserInterface().getTextArea().append("Creating index file\n");
        DataOutputStream indexFile = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("models.idx"));
        indexFile.writeInt(modelList.size());
        for(Model m : modelList) {
            indexFile.writeInt(m.getId());
            indexFile.writeInt(m.getData().length);
        }
        indexFile.flush();
        indexFile.close();
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        Main.getUserInterface().getTextArea().append("An error occured while writing index file\n");
    }
    Main.getUserInterface().getTextArea().append("model.dat and model.idx created\n");
}           

public void loadModels() {
    modelList.clear();
    File[] file = new File("models/").listFiles();
    Main.getUserInterface().getTextArea().append("Found "+ file.length +" model files\n");
    for(File f : file) {
        byte[] data = new byte[(int)f.length()];
        try {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
            in.read(data);
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Main.getUserInterface().getTextArea().append(e.getMessage()+"\n");
        }
        String s = f.getName();
        int id = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(".")));
        Main.getUserInterface().getTextArea().append("ID: "+ id +" Data: "+ data +" Length: "+ (int)f.length()+"\n");   
        Model m = new Model();
        m.setData(data);
        m.setId(id);
        modelList.add(m);
    }       
}
```

Thats the compressor class, but I have no  idea on doing this.

Look, I want to GZip the model files to reduce file size... but then, if I compress the gzipped, files, it'll call them with the .idx which will lead to wrong sizes being used => errors... How am I supposed to work it out so, the files are GZipped inside the .dat, but the .idx has sizes/lengths/w.e of the ungzipped files and how to make the loader support gzip?

Answer (score 0):

1. Compress each individual model separately and concatenate the results to `models.dat` file.
2. Add the compressed lengths and offsets to `models.idx`.
3. When reading models, use compressed lengths and offsets from `models.idx` to read a block of bytes from `models.dat` and uncompress that block, it will result to the uncompressed model.

Or you could use something like 
[ZipFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) class. There you package model files to a zip file and give unique filename to each model and just use this kind of code to fetch the model data. This will be probably slightly slower than using the above method with GZIP but simpler to code.

```
zipFile = new ZipFile("models.zip");
ZipEntry zipEntry = zipFile.getEntry(modelFilename);
InputStream input = getInputStream(zipEntry);
```